# mysql query split column into m

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following database structure:

```
FieldID|Year|Value
a|2011|sugar
a|2012|salt
a|2013|pepper
b|2011|pepper
b|2012|pepper
b|2013|pepper
c|2011|sugar
c|2012|salt
c|2013|salt
```

now I would like to run a query that counts the number of fields for every item in the particular year looking something like this:

```
value|2011|2012|2013
sugar|2|0|0
salt |0|2|1
pepper|1|1|2
```

I used multiple tables for every year before. However the distinct values for 2011,2012 and 2013 might be different (e.g. sugar would only be present in 2011)

For individual years I used:

```
SELECT `Value`, COUNT( `FieldID` ) FROM `Table` WHERE `Year`=2011 GROUP BY `Value`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A1ex07's answer is fine.  However, in MySQL, I prefer this formulation:

```
 SELECT Value, 
        sum(`Year` = 2011) AS cnt2011,
        sum(`Year` = 2012) AS cnt2012,
        sum(`Year` = 2013) AS cnt2013
 FROM t
 GROUP BY value;
```

The use of `count( . . . )` produces the correct answer, but only because the `else` clause is missing.  The default value is `NULL` and that doesn't get counted.  To me, this is a construct that is prone to error.

If you want the above in standard SQL, I go for:

```
 SELECT Value, 
        sum(case when `Year` = 2011 then 1 else 0 end) AS cnt2011,
        sum(case when `Year` = 2012 then 1 else 0 end) AS cnt2012,
        sum(case when `Year` = 2013 then 1 else 0 end) AS cnt2013
 FROM t
 GROUP BY value;
```

Comment: Although I like all three solutions I give this one a +1 for the additional explanation. However, thanks to everyone for solving this so quickly.

Answer (score 0):

You can do pivoting :

```
 SELECT `Value`, 
 COUNT(CASE WHEN `Year` = 2011 THEN FieldID END) AS cnt2011,
 COUNT(CASE WHEN `Year` = 2012 THEN FieldID END) AS cnt2012,
 COUNT(CASE WHEN `Year` = 2013 THEN FieldID END) AS cnt2013
 FROM `Table`
 GROUP BY `Value`
```

Answer (score 0):

It is called Pivot Table, achieve with a chain of CASE statements which apply a 1 or 0 for each condition, then SUM() up the ones and zeros to retrieve a count.

```
SELECT
  Value,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Year = 2011 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 2012,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Year = 2012 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 2012,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Year = 2013 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 2013
FROM Table
GROUP BY Value
```